# String matching objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, string-matching

I need to match my string in this way: `*myString*`
where `*` mean any substring.
which method should I use?

can you help me, please?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat, it's "which method should I use?" "can you help me, please" is probably rhetorical, though I guess you could answer that too.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If it's for iPhone OS 3.2 or later, use NSRegularExpressionSearch.

```
NSString *regEx = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".*%@.*", yourSearchString];
NSRange range = [stringToSearch rangeOfString:regEx options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {

}
```

Comment: I try to use your code but it don't work, but if I use in this way: NSRange range = [@"hello pippo" rangeOfString:@".*pi.*" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]; it work!! Why? In particular if I use regEx to rangeOfString id don't work!?!?!?!

Comment: I noticed that it don't work if textView.text is only a word!!

Comment: @user536926 sorry fixing now.

Answer (score 11):

You can't do an actual search using a * (wildcard character), but you can usually do something that is equivalent:

Equivalent to searching for `theTerm*`:

```
if ([theString hasPrefix:@"theTerm"]) {
```

Equivalent to searching for `*theTerm`:

```
if ([theString hasSuffix:@"theTerm"]) {
```

Or, using the category on `NSString` shown below, the following is equivalent to searching for `*theTerm*`:

```
if ([theString containsString:@"theTerm"]) {
```

A category is simply a new method (like a function) that we add to class. I wrote the following one because it generally makes more sense to me to think of one string containing another rather than dealing with `NSRange`s.

```
// category on NSString
@interface NSString (MDSearchAdditions)
- (BOOL)containsString:(NSString *)aString;
@end

@implementation NSString (MDSearchAdditions)

- (BOOL)containsString:(NSString *)aString {
  return [self rangeOfString:aString].location != NSNotFound;
}

@end
```

Comment: for containsString you can just do `return [self rangeOfString:aString].location != NSNotFound;`

Answer (score 0):

If you need something more evolved, try https://github.com/dblock/objc-ngram.